# Disparate methods. Would like for class to be able to treat them all the same

Tags: python, oop, methods

This is a question about a clean, pythonic way to juggle some different instance methods.

I have a class that operates a little differently depending on certain inputs.  The differences didn't seem big enough to justify producing entirely new classes.  I have to interface the class with one of several data "providers".  I thought I was being smart when I introduced a dictionary:

```
self.interface_tools={'TYPE_A':{ ... various ..., 'data_supplier':self.current_data},
                      'TYPE_B':{ ... various ..., 'data_supplier':self.predicted_data} }
```

Then, as part of the class initialization, I have an input "source_name" and I do ...

```
# ... various ....
self.data_supplier = self.interface_tools[source_name]['data_supplier']
```

`self.current_data` and `self.predicted_data` need the same input parameter, so when it comes time to call the method, I don't have to distinguish them.  I can just call

```
new_data = self.data_supplier(param1)
```

But now I need to interface with a new data source -- call it "TYPE_C" -- and it needs more input parameters.  There are ways to do this, but nothing I can think of is very clean.  For instance, I could just add the new parameters to the old data_suppliers and never use them, so then the call would look like

```
new_data = self.data_supplier(param1,param2,param3)
```

But I don't like that.  I could add an if block

```
if self.data_source != 'TYPE_C':
    new_data = self.data_supplie(param1)
else:
    new_data = self.data_c_supplier(param1,param2,param3)
```

but avoiding if blocks like this was exactly what I was trying to do in the first place with that dictionary I came up with.

So the upshot is: I have a few "data_supplier" routines.  Now that my project has expanded, they have different input lists.  But I want my class to be able to treat them all the same to the extent possible.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Block up the params, either as a list or a class, and make each data supplier just take one argument which is the collection of params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your functions could be making use of [variable length argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

**That said, you could also just make subclasses.** They're fairly cheap to make, and would solve your problem here. This is pretty much the case they were designed for.

Comment: I would up-vote this twice if I could because both points are very valid.

Answer (score 1):

You could make all your data_suppliers accept a single argument and make it a dictionary or a list or even a NamedTuple.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well just use variable length argument lists and/or keyword argument expansion. It's what they're there for.